# Stripe: Argument "customer" must be a string, but got: null (on API request to `GET /v1/customers/{customer}`)

Tags: stripe-payments, mern

```
/ Handle the event

if(eventType==="checkout.session.completed"){ stripe.customers.retrieve(data.customer) .then((customer)=>{ //console.log(customer); //console.log("data",data); createOrders(customer,data) }).catch((err)=>console.log(err.message)) }

// Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the eventres.send().end();});`
```

> I am trying to implement stripe webhooks. process of webhooks working 200 status code correctly. but for adding data in mongodb, I got the error :- Stripe: Argument "customer" must be a string, but got: null (on API request to `GET /v1/customers/{customer}`) . please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

It means the value you passed (`data.customer`) is null.

There isn't always a Customer object associated with a CheckoutSession, it depends what mode you're using it and what you pass to `customer_creation` (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_creation), so this (having a null `data.customer` in the event) can be expected and you need to handle that in your code(for example check if the value exists before trying to use it to retrieve a Stripe Customer object).